# ASP.NET MVC Updatable List View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't find anyone doing this, and I'm trying to get my head around the best way to tackle this issue.

I'd like to take the standard "List View" view in an ASP.NET MVC application, and convert all of the "Labels" to "TextBoxes" and then save any changes made to each record.

The end result would function very similar to the List View in Access. I couldn't find anybody doing this, so any links or ideas are greatly appreciated.

To be clear, I do not want an Edit/Delete button for each record, I want one "Save" button for ALL records at once.

Comment: Oops, voted to close with the wrong type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Definitive guide to model binding with lists formatting](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

[How to model bind to a list by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Lots of Duplicate Questions: [model binding to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+model+binding+to+a+list)

Comment: This looks good, apparently I was using the wrong search terms. ;)