# ASP.NET MVC Master Detail

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm curious as to how others are achieving master detail pages in ASP.NET MVC - **without** JavaScript.

Imagine you have an order details page displaying details for a single order.

In addition to details of the order, you also have a table of the lines on that order.

You would like to be able to edit existing order lines and create new order lines all on the same page.

Basically this is the behaviour we would get from the combination of a GridView and DetailsView in web forms.

Comment: I guess 1) you render master and details 2) you have to keep "selected" master in url or form and 3) the Create/Edit links contains information on where to return after post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Updatable List View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190033/asp-net-mvc-updatable-list-view)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC Updatable List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190033/asp-net-mvc-updatable-list-view)